# jquery replace menu item text on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following simple nav menu (there are no sub-menu items) and I need the text of each menu item to change upon hover. The default text is in the a href tags, the hover text is in the data-item attribute. I've tried variations of some jQuery code posted here, but I'm not getting it right. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menu-item" data-item="Research"><a href="#research">01/08</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item" data-item="Awards"><a href="#awards">02/08</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item" data-item="Education"><a href="#education">03/08</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item" data-item="Publications"><a href="#publications">04/08</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('li > .menu-item').hover(
function() {
    var $this = $(this); // caching $(this)
    $this.data('a href', $this.text());
    $this.document.getElementById("data-item");
},
function() {
    var $this = $(this); // caching $(this)
    $this.text($this.data('a href'));
});
```

Comment: Duplicate IDs in a single document is **invalid HTML**. Consider fixing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

- You shouldn't have multiple elements having same ID. So I have removed the ID attributes from the elements, and changed the selector from `$("#menu-item")` to `$(".menu-item")`.
- `$this.document.getElementById("data-item");` this is not only unnecessary, but incorrect. `$(this)` i.e. the element being hovered doesn't have a `document` property.
- Other than that, you simply need to update the text of `a` element (`$this.find("a")`) using the text from attribute `data-item` (accessible using `$this.data("item")`).

You can find the working snippet below:

```js
$('.menu-item').hover(
  function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var currentText = $this.text();
    var textToUpdate = $this.data("item");
    $this.data('a-href', currentText);
    $this.find("a").text(textToUpdate);
  },
  function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var textToUpdate = $this.data("a-href");
    $this.find("a").text(textToUpdate);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="menu-item" data-item="Research"><a href="#research">01/08</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item" data-item="Awards"><a href="#awards">02/08</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item" data-item="Education"><a href="#education">03/08</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item" data-item="Publications"><a href="#publications">04/08</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: First off, this is exactly the desired result. Thank you also for the useful comments. Newbie question: is there a way to make this work with jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js ?

Comment: @32k_ Yup, that should work with jQuery 2.1.0. I just edited my answer to use that version.

Comment: Many thanks, I had to experiment a bit with the placement of the jQuery library in my code and it works now. One last question: how do I add a fade-in-fade-out effect for the hover? Any hints how I would need to modify your jQuery code snippet?

Comment: @32k_ I have created a snippet [here](https://codepen.io/Nisargshah02/pen/WyPpPd?editors=0010). At the moment I have used `setTimeout` for delay, but I believe there is a way of using jQuery's [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need `mouseover` and `mouseleave`.Also you can create another data attribute like `data-dt` to store the date and avoid the variable to keep track

```js
$('.menu-item').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).find('a').text($(this).data('item'))
})
$('.menu-item').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).find('a').text($(this).data('dt'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item" data-item="Research" data-dt='01/08'><a href="#research">01/08</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item" data-item="Awards" data-dt='03/08'><a href="#awards">02/08</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item" data-item="Education" data-dt='03/08'><a href="#education">03/08</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item" data-item="Publications" data-dt='04/08'><a href="#publications">04/08</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: jQuery's `hover` allows binding handlers for mouse-in and out events: https://api.jquery.com/hover/